# Can not decode a cyrillic string in my servlet

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

Recently I'm working on a new project and `UTF-8` is a must. I don't know why I'm facing this, but it is really strange to me. I really tried everything I knew, but the problem remains.

I'm sending a JSON string to my servlet and here is the servlet part:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    if (action.equals("startProcess")) {
        final String data = request.getParameter("mainData");
        URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("DATA \n" + URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8"));
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try {


            JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8"));
            jsonObj.put("data", jsonArr);
            JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
            System.out.println("insertDtls \n" + jsonObj.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

the `System.out.println("insertDtls \n" + jsonObj.toString());` returns:

this result: `DATA 
[{"department":"1"},{"stampType":"ÐºÑÑÐ³Ð»Ð°Ñ Ð¿ÐµÑÐ°ÑÑ"},{"headCompany":"Ð´Ð°"},{"stampReason":"1"},{"textToPrint":"asd"},{"comments":"da"},{"other":"Ð´ÑÑÐ³Ð¾Ð¹"}]`

I realy don't know what to do here. I'm sure that I'm missing something really small, but I'm not able to spot it. Is it possible to have this string double encoded somehow?

Comment: What characters are there? Latin or other language? I think you can't print most languages using System.out.

Comment: What do you get when you write it to the response instead of the console?

Comment: Can you send the input as a byte array to a file and post a link? Or post the byte[] as hex so we know precisely what's in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String data = request.getParameter("mainData");`

request.getParameter() already decodes mainData parameter. No further decoding is necessary: `URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8")`

If you still want to get raw mainData parameter value use [request.getQueryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) and then decode it: `URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8");`

On client side make sure that when sending a GET request all URL parameters are correctly UTF-8 encoded.
Also on server side make sure your GET parameters are UTF-8 decoded. For example to fix it in Tomcat you must configure *URIEncoding* attribute in  server.xml:
`<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...>`

Comment: It's helpful to mention that `request.setCharacterEncoding()` has only effect on POST request parameters and that setting response content type and encoding has absolutely no effect on the parameters of the current request. The key in OP's case is setting GET request parameter encoding in server configuration (`URIEncoding` and so on). See also [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score -2):

Try running your java process with the -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 parameter.